# angular2 in-memory-web-api only for a part of an application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I was wondering if is possible to configure [angular2 in-memory-web-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) only for a part of an application. I want to reach external endpoints for finished components and use in-memory-web-api for components in development stage.

I've tried to do this in the folowing two ways:

1 - Loading the data in the main and changing the XHRBackend in the components that I want to reach in-memory endpoints;

main.ts

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ...
    { provide: SEED_DATA, useClass: InMemoryDataService }
]);
```

inDevelopmentStage.service.ts

```
@Component({
    providers: [
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService }
    ]
})
```

2 - Loading the data and changing the XHRBackend in the components that I want to reach in-memory endpoints;

inDevelopmentStage.service.ts

```
@Component({
    providers: [
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService }, // in-mem server
        { provide: SEED_DATA, useClass: InMemoryDataService }      // in-mem server data
    ]
})
```

Is there any way that I can achieve this goal?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by [filipesilva](https://github.com/filipesilva) [here](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/issues/15#issuecomment-238885841), the second way should work.

"
Oh sure, you can definitely do this. Each component has it's own injector, which is what resolves providers for itself and all components in that subtree.

Your second example should have worked:

```
@Component({
    providers: [
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService }, // in-mem server
        { provide: SEED_DATA, useClass: InMemoryDataService }      // in-mem server data
    ]
})
```

As for that component and it's subtree, XHRBackend is InMemoryBackendService instead of the service provided by HTTP_PROVIDERS.

Remember that it also applies to any other components in that subtree however. Maybe that's what was going wrong?
"

Thanks Filipe!