# Angular 2 and conflict with XHRBackend

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

I have a problem when I use **ng2-translate** and **XHRBackend**
*{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService }* in my bootstrap
(*with import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA} from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'*)

I get exception:
"ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: null"

I think that **ng2-translat**e tries to get data but using "fake" **XHRBackend** doesn't get anything.

Without this line *{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService }* everything works fine.
Can anybody explain how I can manage to it?
I have angular 2 RC4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't need this line. AFAIK this is only for demonstration purposes when no real server can be used.

Comment: I need this line for another part of my application. So I have to use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637381/angular2-in-memory-web-api-only-for-a-part-of-an-application